# Prevent multiple save clicks based on RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a save button that when clicked creates a new user with all the required fields. If clicked multiple times, multiple users get created. What I would like to do is once the save button is clicked, check that all RequiredFieldValidators have been validated (aka: all required fields have data in them) once that has happened, I would then like to disable the save button. The problem I am facing is I dont know how to have a conditional around ALL the RequiredFieldValidators on the page. Additionally my SaveButton is already calling a function to clear out all the 'required' tags so that will still need to take place.

Here is my button

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-xs filterbutton" Text="Save" runat="server" ValidationGroup="DemoSummary" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="ClearRequiredTag();" />
```

Which then calls

```
        function ClearRequiredTag() {
            var list = document.all;

            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i].setAttribute("RequiredTag", 'false');
            }
        }
```

This is then where all the RequiredFieldValidators are run.

So far I have tried this, but with no avail as ClearRequiredTag() will return true regardless so what I would like there instead is to check all RequiredFieldValidators instead.

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#<%=cmdSubmit.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                    if (ClearRequiredTag()) {
                        $("#<%=cmdSubmit.ClientID%>").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#<%=cmdSubmit.ClientID%>").show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: why don't you disable the button for a period of time, or simply, until you return from processing the new user?

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the value in the RequiredTag attribute, use this jquery selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ to select all inputs that have the RequiredTag attribute, then use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ to loop through them and get the val() of each one. If they all have values, disable your submit button and proceed.